# What all types of file can be read with File class c#?

Tags: c#, .net, file, readfile

I have tried reading Text File and XML File with [File Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx), it works fine.I was wondering if we can read excel or word or other types.

```
var str = File.ReadAllLines("Test.xlsx");
```

While debugging ,**str** shows special characters.
Hope I had made question clear.Kindly Advise
Down votes are welcomed,if accompanied by proper comment to improve :).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: with File.ReadAllLines you get just text from the file, so answer is: every file with plain text inside :)

Comment: you can have a look at [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus) if you need to work with excel files.

Comment: Thanks @MaksimSimkin

Comment: A better approach is `File.ReadAllBytes()`. That can read every file type without problems. Those problems only come when you want to make sense of those `byte`s. Which is the part you should be thinking (and reading) about.

Comment: `xlsx` files are *zipped* packages of  XML files. You use the Open XML SDK or EPPlus to treat them as one Excel file, or the [System.IO.Packaging.Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package(v=vs.110).aspx) class to treat them as one zip with many files

Answer (score 1):

XML and Text Files are plain files, where text on screen appear like they are in file. That's why `File.ReadAllLines` work.

With Excel, it is different. It has encoded logic in file, which when read by a special programs (read MSExcel) decodes it and displays it correctly on screen.

Think of it as a encoded or obfuscated file read by programs specially defined to decrypt them.

To read Excel file in DotNet, you can use them to be transferred into `DataSet`/`DataTable` like this [Read Excel File in C# (Example)](https://coderwall.com/p/app3ya/read-excel-file-in-c)

Comment: You don't need Interop with `xlsx` files, "just" Open XML or EPPlus. The file  is a zipped package of XML files, so one *could* treat the contents as text. It's not *obfuscated* - it's a well defined format

Comment: Agree to a point, but still even if that file is opened as xml, it won't make any sense. To make sense you need MsExcel or DataSet/DataTable.

Comment: That was only for the old `xls` format. You can read `xlsx` as an Excel spreadsheet with [Microsoft's Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg575571.aspx), or any of the libraries that understand the format. After that, [you could query it with LINQ](https://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LinqExample) if you want. The whole point of the Open Office XML standard was that you didn't need Excel or OLEDB to read the files

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Here is the difference, like you said xlsx is zipped package of XML files, which is required by special programs like MSExcel to make sense of it.

Comment: Did you check the links to MSDN? That's no special program. This is only *one* SDK that can be used to read xlsx files. There are [Ruby gems](https://github.com/cxn03651/write_xlsx) that do the same without requiring Excel, [Python libraries](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/), even Javascript libraries that can read them. No special sofrware program required. DataTables aren't required either, since all libraries can deal with Excel objectss like Cells, Ranges, Tables, Sheets etc. DataTables *were* required if you used eg OLEDB.

Answer (score 1):

With `File.ReadAllLines` you can read text files (and XML is -as we know- as well a text file).

Of course then function reads other kind of data files as well - but you will not get meaningful results. The binary data is interpreted as characters. This will not work for Office files.

Answer (score 1):

[The MSDN documentation for File.ReadAllLines()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) states that:

> This method attempts to automatically detect the encoding of a file based on the presence of byte order marks. Encoding formats UTF-8 and UTF-32 (both big-endian and little-endian) can be detected.

Therefore you can read text files with one of the UTF encodings it supports.  To read files that use other encodings (e.g. Windows ANSI, non-Latin text) you should use the overload that takes an `Encoding` parameter.